# why do I get "no valid constructor" exception?

Tags: java

I am serializing a class. I have the following structure:

```
class A { class B { public B(); ... } }
class C extends A { class D extends A.B implements Serializable { public D(); } }
```

I can write objects of the type C.D, but whenever I try to read them back, I get the exception:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: C$D; C$D; no valid constructor
```

any ideas?

Just to make it clear, it says here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InvalidClassException.html that this exception is thrown when there is no constructor that accepts no parameters. But I do have these constructors.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that class `A.B` needs to be `Serializable`. If you add that interface, you can happily both save and restore objects.

When you serialize a class which extends a nested class (certainly a corner case!) it needs access to the parent's member variables, since otherwise you would have a partial object. That involves serializing the parent.

The error message could certainly be better, yes - usually the "no valid constructor" is only gotten in the presence of circular dependencies or (as you said) missing no-args constructors.